# My top bar is broken

Tags: gnome, statusbar

After drag & dropping by accident a `.xpm` file on the top bar, the right-hand side is now totally missing (see attached example of missing pieces) :(

[image]

How can I get this back, please?

**Update**: It seems I am using `gnome (flashback) Metacity` (and no I don't want to switch to Unity just in case somebody's asking :)

**Update2:** Running `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/` solved my problem!

Comment: tried that numerous times to no avail.